# In bash scripting, count1 = `cat $affected_ip|wc -l`;echo $count1;

Tags: linux, bash, syntax

```
count1=`cat $affected_ip|wc -l`;
echo $count1;
```

Will these lines of code fetch the count from the file named afffected_ip and print the output?

Need help to perform above task.

Comment: No, the line is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: No spaces either side of the "=" sign shoudl sort you out.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need the semi-colons at the ends of lines in bash, only between commands if you have multiple comamnds on a single text line.

Comment: Is the file actually called "affected_ip" or is the name in the $affected_ip variable?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to count the number of ips affected etc, etc, whereby you have 1 ip per line.

You are not too far off actually.

First of all ( as mentioned by user simon3270 ) , you dont need thesemicolons in this snippet. Variables for assignment in bash dont need the $ too in this scenario.

In your case, running at bash shell

```
wc - l < affected_ips.txt
```

And you will get the number of lines / IPs. Grepping etc could help you if you have particular patters to discern.